# kafka "stops working" after a large message is enqueued

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm running kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 and a java-based producer/consumer. With messages ~70 KB everything works fine. However, after the producer enqueues a larger, 70 MB  message, kafka appears to stop delivering the messages to the consumer. I.e. not only is the large message not delivered but also subsequent smaller messages. I know the producer succeeds because I used kafka callback for the confirmation and I can see the messages in the kafka message log.

kafka config custom changes:

```
message.max.bytes=200000000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=200000000
```

consumer config:

```
props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes",   "200000000");
props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "200000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the size of the messages the consumer can consume so it doesn't get stuck trying to read a message that is to big.

```
max.partition.fetch.bytes (default value is 1048576 bytes)
```

> The maximum amount of data per-partition the server will return. The
>   maximum total memory used for a request will be #partitions *
>   max.partition.fetch.bytes. This size must be at least as large as the
>   maximum message size the server allows or else it is possible for the
>   producer to send messages larger than the consumer can fetch. If that
>   happens, the consumer can get stuck trying to fetch a large message on
>   a certain partition.

Comment: I'm already setting max.patition.fetch.bytes as shown in the consumer config snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

What helped was upping the java heap size.